# How to select users without specific one to many rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Consider the following data set:

users table:

```
id (int) email (string)
1        first@example.com
2        second@example.com
```

order_items table:

```
id (int) user_id (int) generation (string)   
1        1             '11'
2        1             '12'
2        1             '12.50'
3        1             '16.00'
4        2             '11' 
5        2             '12'
```

#### UPDATED question

How can I select users which doesn't have order_items with generation 16.00 and have at least one order_item?

So:

```
email
second@example.com
```

Comment: what is `generation` column ?

Comment: If you don't understand the logic behind Darshan answer, write all the columns you have inside both tables. Only then someone can actually help you.

Comment: I'm edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Returning Users who don't have order item with generation 16 included users with no orders at all.

Assuming you have some kind of id column in order_items table:

```
select u.* from users u
left outer join order_items oi on (u.id = oi.user_id and oi.generation = 16)
where oi.id is null;
```

Otherwise use whatever primary key you have in order_items in the where condition to be NULL.

*Updated to include answer for the question in comment*

2) Returning users who don't have order item with generation 16 but have least one order.

```
select distinct u.* from users u
left outer join order_items oi16 on (u.id = oi.user_id and oi.generation = 16)
join order_items oiother on (u.id = oiother.user_id and oiother.generation != 16)
where oi16.id is null;
```

We do the filtering by using a second (normal) join which only returns users where it finds matching rows from the order_items table.

Here we need the distinct because the second join will multiply your rows depending on how many other orders the user have.

Alternatively you can also do a count or sum like this:

```
select u.*, count(distinct oiother.id) from users u
left outer join order_items oi16 on (u.id = oi.user_id and oi.generation = 16)
join order_items oiother on (u.id = oiother.user_id and oiother.generation != 16)
where oi16.id is null
group by u.id;
```

This will give you also how many other order items each returned user have. Or omit the count completely and using group by just to return distinct items.

Comment: thanks for answer, I'm updated question to select also users with at least one order item, can you help?

Comment: Thanks, but results are strange... I've created http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5acfe/3/0 and it seems work, but for my production data set the results includes also users which has '16.00' randomly... :/

Comment: the generation column is varchar, maybe it's problem?

Comment: MySQL is deterministic and the query has no 'random' factor so unless data changes it should always return the same results. If you consider it as a number storing it as a varchar could be a problem. 16 is equal with 16.0 but '16' is not equal with '16.0'. If you cannot change the type you can still use numbers in the condition and mysql will match the column type for you which is still better than having wrong results but be aware that in this case indexes on generation column cannot be used.

Comment: generation column should be varchar and it is, the values which it can have are '11', '12', '12.50' and '16.00', it is treat like "version number" in our app

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT EXISTS() like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM order_items o
                 WHERE o.userid = u.id
                      AND o.generation = 16)
```

That checks if there is a record for this user with order.generation = 16, and if there isn't it selects him.

Or not in()

```
SELECT * FROM Users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN(SELECT userid FROM order_items o
                  WHERE o.generation = 16)
```

That selects the list of users who have order.generation = 16, and select every id except them.

Comment: The first one is a dependent subquery which performs very badly. The second is a bit better but still not optimal. It's fetching data unnecessarily and doing a NOT IN using a possibly large dataset should be also avoided. A simple JOIN performs much better in this case.

Comment: The first one is perfectly fine, and left join won't necesseraly perform better! And its a lot better then the NOT IN() so I really don't know what you are talking about @KárolyNagy

Comment: I invite you to test all this 3 queries, I think u'll be surprised . My IN query select exactly the same amount of data your left join selects, and so does my EXISTS()

Comment: This is not a competition. I'm glad @Karol Fiturski now has multiple options to choose from.

Comment: Of course it returns the same amount of rows. Both of your solutions are answering the same questions correctly. I just wanted to point out the the big O notation complexity is higher. That's all. At the end of the day it comes down to the actual dataset and what works best in the particular case.

Comment: I know it isn't, but you misdirected him.. so I corrected you.

Answer (score -1):

Following query should give you the desired output:

***update***

changed query as per the new result format in the question

As we want the data only from generation table, join with user table is not needed anymore. Here's the updated query:

```
select id, generation
from mytable where id not in (
  select id from mytable
  where generation = 16
  group by id
  );
```

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/319de/6/0) for it.

Comment: This is not what he asked for!

Comment: This is only returning users who have at least one order.